# Colour proof - digital

Tags: color

I would like to get a colour proof done at the printers. What's the best paper weight to do this on? And would A3 be ok?

Comment: You'll get a better answer by asking your printer.

Comment: Color is very complicated and affected by lots of things, such as how the paper absorbs ink. You can digitally print the same file on two different printers, hold them up and compare obvious color differences. So for a proof, you want to use exactly what you will be using for the final product (same device, paper, settings, etc)

Answer (score 2):

A "color proof" is not just a random paper on a random size for your print.

A color proof should be done in the exact same paper, on the same size, on the same type of print, same settings and color profiles you need for your project.

So define your project and print one page as a color proof.